# what media won't play?

Tags: mp3, codecs, media, file-type

Leaving aside DRM media, are there specific codecs or filetypes which simply won't play on Linux?

I've installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` but didn't get `libavcodec-extra-53` for example.  While there's no specific filetype I'm looking for, more of a list of what won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In five years I've never run into anything (DRM excluded) that can't play. Some things need restricted codecs, some required VLC... But everything played in the end.

That's not to say there aren't rare codecs out there (there are) but unless you're doing pretty niche stuff, you're unlikely to bump into them.

Answer (score 1):

If you install a program like VLC, you'll be able to play almost every media format under the sun. The only issues you'll run into is when you want to play DRM protected files or protected DVDs. The latter can be rectified by following the readily available guides all over the net for installing the DVD decryptors(although the legality of installing them varies from country to country).

When it comes to DRM content generally the answer is "No" since most DRM systems don't support Linux, but running the Windows Programs required for some DRMs is possible using things like WINE. Netflix support has been dealt with thanks to a nice developer that has designed and pre-built a Wine+Silverlight+Firefox solution for dealing with Netflix's and Lovefilm's DRM. Other services like Amazon and Hulu use Flash DRM which IS officially supported on Linux so no issues there. Reading Adobe protected Epubs is simple enough by installing a slightly older version of Adobe Reader in WINE.

As for dealing with other DRMs you'll have to look up online if somebody has found a workaround for that specific DRM Service.

Comment: how do you know it's silverlight and not ____ when you encounter something which won't play.  Quite often there's no particular information.

Comment: @Thufir Often whatever program or service you're using will inform you what you are lacking. Netflix, for instance, will complain about the lack of Silverlight. However a workaround for such Services using Silverlight was developed in November and works for pretty much any of these services(As I said Above). Although Netflix has just announced their move to HTML5 to be very soon, and released a test version in the form of HTML5 app for ARM-based ChromeOS devices. The only thing preventing them from switching is apparently the lack of adoption of certain DRM standards for HTML5.

Comment: @Thufir Also another method is to simply search the site of the Software/Service to see if it says anything about Required Plugins/Software. Many times WINE support for that software is available but it can sometimes be complicated setting up the right dependencies in WINE for the Software(For Example: WMA DRM protection requires WindowsMediaPlayer and that requires other dependencies which can be a pain to setup). Also note that WINE programs often don't work with Linux programs so you'll need say the Windows version of Firefox installed as well as the Windows specific DRM plugin for Firefox.